# Specs2: How to Test if "abc" contains all of "aabb"

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

Specs2 does provide a `containsAllOf` matcher but I can't get it to work the way I want. I have two Strings A and B, and I want to test that all Chars that occur in B are present in A.

My best try so far was

```
A.toCharArray.toSeq must containAllOf(B.toCharArray.toSeq)
```

But this fails with errors like

> WrappedArray(**a**, b, c, d, ...) does not contain S, **a**, V, H, I, ... and
>   **must not** contain ...

1. The WrappedArray does contain the characters it allegedly doesn't according to Specs2
2. Why is there a test for elements A must **not** contain? I don't want ot test equality, I want to test if B is a "subset" of A (but not in the strict set-theoretic definition of set)

How can I write a working spec for this scenario?

Comment: Try `A.toSet must containAllOf(B.toSet)` - `toSet` called on a String will return a Set of the (unique) `Char`s in the String.

Comment: This does not compile, `A.toSet.toSeq` etc does and passes the test - however that does not explain why the above does not work, when (in my opinion) it totally should :? The name `containAllOf` clearly does not imply that they have to be contained exactly once and that the left side is not allowed to contain more characters than the right side...

Comment: Hmm, seems containAllOf returns true if the first sequence contains within it somewhere the whole of the second sequence, contiguously and in order. It is not a `Set` comparison, but a `Seq` comparison. That would mean `A.toSet.toSeq` would likely fail as well for some inputs (eg. try B = "bbaa") unless the resulting `Seq`s were sorted first (`A.toSet.toSeq.sorted` etc.).

Comment: Which version are you using? Can you try 2.3.1 and 'contain(allOf(B.toSeq:_*))'?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.1, unfortunately your suggestion shows the exact same symptoms

Comment: This passes ok for me (on 2.3.1): `"abcdeba".toSeq must contain(allOf("bcaa".toSeq:_*))`. Can you please update your question with the exact `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I've chosen this variant:

```
B.toSeq.map(c => A must contain(c))
```

I'm still open to suggestions, but if there is no cleaner solution I might (for the first time) answer my own question.

Or is this one of the cases where I suspect Specs2 to test a thing, when it actually doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

This does not use containsAllOf but should work:

```
/* turn A into a Map for quick contains lookup */
val theAs = A.map(x=> (x,x)).toMap

/* if resulting list has length greater than 0, 
 * then there is something in A that is not in B*/
B.filterNot(theAs.contains).length must === 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which is certainly valid. But for me, this is a little bit too much logic for a test case that expresses such a simple situation ;)

Comment: No worries :) I hope this can still be of help to someone.